# Change height of formSheet in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, uimodalpresentationformsh

I just have one question related to presenting a from sheet view controller in iOS 8. In iOS 7 I was able to change the height of the view controller using the last line of code in the function below:

```
SendRemainingEvaluationsViewController *sendRemainingEvaluationViewController = [[[SendRemainingEvaluationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SendRemainingEvaluationsViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sendRemainingEvaluationViewController] autorelease];
    navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

    //To Change the default size of the viewController which is presented in UIModalPresentationFormSheet presentation style
    navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(navigationController.view.superview.frame.origin.x, navigationController.view.superview.frame.origin.y, navigationController.view.superview.frame.size.width, 230);
```

But this does not work on iOS 8, not sure why? Does anyone knows what is the problem? any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking it, I could figure out the problem. After initializing the view navigation controller, its superview is nil and you can't access it right after presenting it. As a workaround, you can change the frame of its superview in the viewwillAppear of the view controller you're trying to present as you can see below:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.parentViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(self.parentViewController.view.superview.frame.origin.x, self.parentViewController.view.superview.frame.origin.y, self.parentViewController.view.superview.frame.size.width, 230);
}
```

This should work.